# Validating App Error: An SSL error has occurred and secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: xcode, ssl, submission

In XCode, I tried to upload a new version of an app A, but it gives this error EVERYTIME.
Then I had another app B to be uploaded, it goes ok (validate ok, and upload ok). Then I return to the app A, it still give the same error.

I tried:
1. Restart XCode.
2. Restart Mac.
3. Clean All and Re-Archive.

Still the same error. What gives?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

restart xcode or restart machine , again if you get same error upload after 24 hours i succeded for this error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, either, but I think you can try uploading your app directly, that should be OKey.

Comment: Nope. I found out that this problem is due to a new feature I wanted to add to my app by adding an SDK. Apparently this SDK is causing this problem. So I just removed the SDK and then it works ok. No solution though.